# JavaScript time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

```
var today = new Date();
        jQuery(function () {
        var preferences_clock_hide = isPreferenceOn('preferences_clock');
        if (!preferences_clock_hide) {
            if(today.dst()){
            jQuery('.server-time').countdown({since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), compact: true, format: 'HMS', timezone: -4});
        }else{
            jQuery('.server-time').countdown({since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), compact: true, format: 'HMS', timezone: -5});
        }
    }
});
        Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
            var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
            return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
        }

        Date.prototype.dst = function() {
            return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
        }
```

This code should change the time if we are in DST, but apparently .dst() doesn't go true, although we are in DST now. It is probably a small mistake, but I hope you guys can help me.

P.S. I am new at asking questions here, so I do not know the meta. Sorry about it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I changed the code to this:`

```
var today = new Date();
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}
jQuery(function () {
        if(today.dst()) {
            jQuery('.server-time').countdown({
                since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), 
                compact: true, 
                format: 'HMS', 
                timezone: -4
                });
        }else{
            jQuery('.server-time').countdown({
                since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), 
                compact: true, 
                format: 'HMS', 
                timezone: -5
            });
        }
});
`
```

When I test it in the console, today.dst() returns true, but the timezone does not change for some reason.

EDIT2:
For some reason today.dst() is true, but the code goes in the else.

Answer (score 0):

Not expert and I don't know what you are trying to do in this line

```
jQuery('.server-time').countdown({since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), compact: true, format: 'HMS', timezone: -4});
```

But can you try this :

```
    var today = new Date();
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}
jQuery(function () {
    var preferences_clock_hide = isPreferenceOn('preferences_clock');
    if (!preferences_clock_hide) {
        if(today.dst()) {
            jQuery('.server-time').countdown({
                since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), 
                compact: true, 
                format: 'HMS', 
                timezone: -4
                });
        }
    }else{
        jQuery('.server-time').countdown({
            since: new Date({/literal}{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y, %m-1, %d"}{literal}), 
            compact: true, 
            format: 'HMS', 
            timezone: -5
            });
    }
});
```

If you check the console you will see this error : today.dst is not a function

Edit : Sorry for bad English I couldn't explain it very well, just check @Undefine answer it explains everything
Just debug your code using browser tools and you can see why you don't get expected result.

```
var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
console.log(Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset()));
return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Both will return same value because you are using getTimezoneOffset in both functions which return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time.

```
return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
```

this will return FALSE for the same reason, getTimezoneOffset used in both and for me I have -60 min so the result is -60 < -60 and that is FALSE
I hope that helps!

Comment: 1) Thank you for your reply
2) It did not gave me an error actually
3) Now dst should be true, but it returns false for some reason

Answer (score 0):

@Niroda suggested the rigth code. The problem is in visibility scope of variables.

As I know, **JavaScript read** the code **in 2 iteration** - the first time it remember code(for variable only names, but including functions content) and scan for errors and the second - it sets the value of the variables and run the code.

If you use a default function sintaxis `function functionName(...) {...}` then you may put it in any part of the code and it will work because JS remembered a function

But if you use variable option `functionName = function(...) {...}` then JS will remember **variable name** but it doesn't know that it is a function and while running your code `today.dst()` equals `undefined` at the first iteration and only then on the second iteration (after running everything higher this line) it will set it to the function.

So if you used the same code on click it will be ok, but now yours `if` statement check the function result before initialization of this function.

Hope you got it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me in general. But the Niroda's code does not work for some reason.